# How can I get Emacs cc-mode functions that refer to functions to work with Java methods?

Tags: java, emacs

As [noted in cc-mode's documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Indentation-Commands.html), functions like `c-indent-defun` and `c-mark-function` "can't be used to reindent a nested brace construct, such as a nested class or function, or a Java method." The same goes for `c-beginning-of-defun` and its ilk.

Does anyone have a solution to get these functions working with Java methods, or maybe Java-specific replacements?

Comment: There's a java-mode that's based on cc-mode.  Does it not work for you?  If you look in cc-mode source for emacs 23.1, you'll see a bunch of java-specific logic inside the cc-mode elisp files.

Comment: I am using java-mode, but the functions that involve moving in relation to functions don't work in a useful fashion. As their documentation says, they work on the top-level structure, so in your usual java source file doing `c-beginning-of-defun` brings you to the top of the class, not the method.

If there are other, java specific functions that do work, I certainly can't find them and would greatly appreciate being told what they are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Java, but Emacs has a [Java Development Environment](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaDevelopmentEnvironment).  [JDEE Jalopy claims](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JdeeJalopy) to do beautifying work.  That should help you get the functions you mention.